# Python: Name not defined error even though function is clearly defined before call

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, compiler-errors

I'm new to python and having a weird issue with function definitions. I have checked around the forums and made sure to define my function before calling it, however that has not helped the issue. I keep getting a name not defined error when I try to call literally function in this one particular method.

```
from eight_puzzle import Puzzle
import math


################################################################
### Node class and helper functions provided for your convience.
### DO NOT EDIT!
################################################################
class Node:
    """
    A class representing a node.
    - 'state' holds the state of the node.
    - 'parent' points to the node's parent.
    - 'action' is the action taken by the parent to produce this node.
    - 'path_cost' is the cost of the path from the root to this node.
    """
    def __init__(self, state, parent, action, path_cost):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
        self.path_cost = path_cost

    def gen_child(self, problem, action):
        """
        Returns the child node resulting from applying 'action' to this node.
        """
        return Node(state=problem.transitions(self.state, action),
                    parent=self,
                    action=action,
                    path_cost=self.path_cost + problem.step_cost(self.state, action))

    @property
    def state_hashed(self):
        """
        Produces a hashed representation of the node's state for easy
        lookup in a python 'set'.
        """
        return hash(str(self.state))

################################################################
### Node class and helper functions provided for your convience.
### DO NOT EDIT!
################################################################
def retrieve_solution(node,num_explored,num_generated):
    """
    Returns the list of actions and the list of states on the
    path to the given goal_state node. Also returns the number
    of nodes explored and generated.
    """
    actions = []
    states = []
    while node.parent is not None:
        actions += [node.action]
        states += [node.state]
        node = node.parent
    states += [node.state]
    return actions[::-1], states[::-1], num_explored, num_generated

################################################################
### Node class and helper functions provided for your convience.
### DO NOT EDIT!
################################################################
def print_solution(solution):
    """
    Prints out the path from the initial state to the goal given
    a tuple of (actions,states) corresponding to the solution.
    """
    actions, states, num_explored, num_generated = solution
    print('Start')
    for step in range(len(actions)):
        print(puzzle.board_str(states[step]))
        print()
        print(actions[step])
        print()
    print('Goal')
    print(puzzle.board_str(states[-1]))
    print()
    print('Number of steps: {:d}'.format(len(actions)))
    print('Nodes explored: {:d}'.format(num_explored))
    print('Nodes generated: {:d}'.format(num_generated))


################################################################
### Skeleton code for your Astar implementation. Fill in here.
################################################################
class Astar:
    """
    A* search.
    - 'problem' is a Puzzle instance.
    """
    def __init__(self, problem):
        self.problem = problem
        self.init_state = problem.init_state
        self.num_explored = 0
        self.num_generated = 1




    def selectState(self, listOfStates):
        '''
        Selects the loweset cost node for expansion based on f(n) = g(n) + h(n)
        '''
        lowestCostPath = listOfStates[0].path_cost
        index = int(1)
        lowestNodeIndex = int(0)
        while index != len(listOfStates):
            scannedPathCost = listOfStates[index].path_cost
            if index  < scannedPathCost:
                lowestCostPath = scannedPathCost
                lowestNodeIndex = index
            index += 1
        return listOfStates[lowestNodeIndex]


    def f(self,node, method):
        '''
        Returns a lower bound estimate on the cost from root through node
        to the goal.
        '''
        return node.path_cost + self.h(node, method)



    def getManhattanDistance(self, node):
        '''
        Evaluates the manhattan distance for a given state 
        '''
        iterator = int(0)
        misplacedCount = int(0)
        totalDistance = int(0)
        while iterator != len(node.state):
            if iterator != node.state[iterator] and node.state[iterator] != 0:
                misplacedCount = misplacedCount + 1
                xCurrent = int(node.state[iterator]/3)
                yCurrent = int(node.state[iterator]%3)
                xDesired = int(iterator/3)
                yDesired = int(iterator%3)
                totalDistance = totalDistance + int(abs(xCurrent - xDesired)) + int(abs(yCurrent - yDesired))
            iterator = iterator + 1
        return totalDistance + misplacedCount

    def h(self,node, method='man'):
        '''
        Returns a lower bound estimate on the cost from node to the goal
        using the different heuristics. 
        '''
        ################################################################
        ### Your code here.
        ################################################################
        if method == 'man':
            self.getManhattanDistance(node)
            return -1
        elif method == 'rowcol':
            return -1 # compute rowcol heuristic
        elif method == 'misplaced':
            return -1 # compute misplaced tiles the number of tiles out of place
        elif method == 'null':
            return -1 # compute null heuristic
        else:
            return 0

    def method_stats(self, board, trials=100, method='man'):
        '''
        Returns an mean and standard deviation of the number of nodes expanded
        '''
        # write code here to randomly generate puzzles and
        # compute the mean and standard deviation of the number
        # nodes expanded. You can use np.mean() and np.std()

        expanded_mean = 0.
        expanded_std = 0.
        for t in range(trials):
            puzzle = Puzzle(board).shuffle()
            solver = Astar(puzzle)
            actions, states, num_explored, num_generated = solver.solve(method=method)
            ############################################################
            ### Compute upper bound for branching factor and update b_hi
            ### Your code here.
            ############################################################
        return expanded_mean, expanded_std

    def anotherFunction(self, node, method):
        return 1

    def generateStatesFor(self, node, method, listOfStates):
        '''
        Decides how to select an action from a list of available actions
        '''
    def solve(self, method='man'):
        node = Node(state = self.init_state,
            parent = None,
            action = None,
            path_cost = 0)
        num_explored = int(0)
        num_generated = int(0)
        listOfStates = []
        listOfStates.append(node)
        print(listOfStates[0].state)
        anotherFunction(self, node, method)
        return retrieve_solution(node, num_explored=num_explored, num_generated=num_generated)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Simple puzzle test
   ## board = [[3,1,2],
    ##         [4,0,5],
    ##         [6,7,8]]
    board = [[7,2,4],
             [5,0,6],
             [8,3,1]]

    puzzle = Puzzle(board)
    solver = Astar(puzzle)
    solution = solver.solve()
    ##print_solution(solution)

    # Harder puzzle test
    board = [[7,2,4],
             [5,0,6],
             [8,3,1]]

    puzzle = Puzzle(board)
    solver = Astar(puzzle)
    ##solution = solver.solve()
    ##print(len(solution[0]))

    # branching factor test
    method='man'
    emean, estd = solver.method_stats(board, trials=100, method=method)
    ##print('mean and standard deviation: {0:.2f}, {1:.2f} using heuristic: {2}'.format(emean, estd, method))
```

The Error code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/-/Downloads/HW1 2/code/my_hw1.py", line 214, in <module>
solution = solver.solve() File "/Users/-/Downloads/HW1 2/code/my_hw1.py", line 200, in solve
anotherFunction(self, node, method) NameError: name 'anotherFunction' is not defined [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

As you can see, the function calling it is on line 200 and the function is defined at line 185. Any idea what the issue could be? I am also able to call the exact same "anotherFunction" method from other methods which aren't solve. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put code in your post, and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Added the full file

Comment: Your indentation seems off, but I _think_ your issue is that you just need to add `self.` in front of your call to `anotherFunction()`.

Comment: Nope that doesn't change anything. Also the another function call works in literally every other function in the class as is.

Comment: Could you please check if the indentation in your question matches the indentatioon of your real code. Something doesn't look right here.

Comment: Yeah everything matches now

Comment: Addtionally to putting `self.` infront, like Matthias said, remove the explicit `self` argument when you call the function => `self.anotherFunction(node, method)`.

Comment: You must access those methods through `self`.... Please read a basic Python tutorial on classes. Python != Java

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function with "self" as an argument, you need to call that function from the class in which it is defined. For example, if you have an instance of the class myClass where anotherFunction is defined, the syntax would be myClass.anotherFunction(node, method). The "self" argument in the definition indicates anotherFunction is a member function of whatever class it is defined in - I would need to see more of your code to know what class that is.

Comment: It's not an instance, I'm calling it from within the class and it still does not compile.

Comment: Of course it's an instance of the class or what do you think this line in your code does: `solver = Astar(puzzle)`?